# Append JSON response to tableview -Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, parse-cloud-code

I'm calling a PFCloud function that returns a json response of user credit cards, I'd like to display some of the card data. I've got an array I tried to append to and it's failing to display. I called this function in viewDidLoad.

```
func loadCards(){

    if let customer = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("stripe_customer_id") as? String {

        PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("listCards", withParameters: ["customerId": customer], block: { (success: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                println(error)
            }
            else {
                let responseString = success as? NSArray

                    if let cardToDisplay = responseString!.valueForKey("cardId") as? NSArray{


                        println(cardToDisplay)
                        self.displayCards.addObject(cardToDisplay)


                    }

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        })
    }

}



// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    println(self.displayCards.count)
    return self.displayCards.count

}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: CardsTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CardsTableViewCell

 self.displayCards[indexPath.row] = cell.card.text!
return cell
}
```

Here are my logs from the console:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
(
"card_16v8teBnRIkk4qBepmuz2Mlk",
"card_16ymjoBnRIkk4qBeirtCdYdn",
"card_16ymfzBnRIkk4qBebvP4wwNO",
"card_16ymfzBnRIkk4qBeoRUVccws",
"card_16ymaPBnRIkk4qBeK2ju6ckP",
"card_16ylqyBnRIkk4qBeffUN2bwo",
"card_16ylq3BnRIkk4qBePGngNz8H"
)
1
```

Comment: You need to reload the table view after getting the data.

Comment: I tried that it  returns 1 and the same json response but doesn't load in tableview

Comment: Update your question with your attempt to reload the table after getting the data.

Comment: it's updated...after the if statement

Comment: You must call `reloadData` on the main thread.

Comment: I've also tried 

  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You need to reload te tableView in main thread. As you got into background to make the request, you need to do:

  ```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
      self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
  ```

  Instead of just `self.tableView.reloadData()`
- `cardToDisplay` appears to be an array, so change `self.displayCards.addObject(cardToDisplay)` to `self.displayCards = cardToDisplay`
- The line `self.displayCards[indexPath.row] = cell.card.text!` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should be the other way round.. You should set the text as the `self.displayCards[indexPath.row]` is. So it should be `cell.card.text = self.displayCards[indexPath.row]`

Comment: I've tried this, the table still doesn't load unfortunately